# Flutter keyboard hide Material TextFormField

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, keyboard

When I tap on TextFormField and the keyboard appear, goes over the TextFormField and I cannot see what I'm writing.

I'm trting some things:

- add resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true to Scaffold widget
- add SingleChildScrollView
- and other things

Expected behaviour: tap on TextFormField, keyboard opens and then the TextFormField move up to be visible.

Page file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project/components/loginButton.dart';
import 'package:project/components/szInput.dart';
import 'package:project/dialogs/infoDialog.dart';
import 'package:project/models/reservation.dart';
import 'package:project/models/turnInfo.dart';
import 'package:project/models/user.dart';
import 'package:project/pages/dashboardPage.dart';
import 'package:project/repository/api.dart';
import 'package:project/ui.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:loader_overlay/loader_overlay.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final loginErrorProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);

class _WaveCustomPaint extends CustomPainter {
  Color backgroundColor;
  _WaveCustomPaint({required this.backgroundColor});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var painter = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    var path = Path();
    var height = size.height;
    var width = size.width;

    path.moveTo(0, height / 7 + height / 5);
    var des1 = width / 4;
    var des2 = height / 4.8 + height / 10; //height/5 /2
    path.quadraticBezierTo(des1, des2, width / 2, height / 4.6 + height / 10);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(width / 1.02 + width / 4.2,
        height / 3.5 + height / 10, width + 2, height / 5);
    path.lineTo(width, height);
    path.lineTo(0, height);
    path.lineTo(0, height / 3 + height / 5);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, painter);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

class LoginPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<LoginPage> createState() => _state();
}

class _state extends ConsumerState<LoginPage> {
  final ApiRepository api = ApiRepository();
  final _nameAndSurnameController = TextEditingController(text: "");
  final _pnrController = TextEditingController(text: "");

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    checkRememberLogin();
  }

  onLoginButtonPressed() async {
    try {
      context.loaderOverlay.show();
      ref.read(loginErrorProvider.notifier).state = false;
      String pnr = _pnrController.text;
      String nameSurname = _nameAndSurnameController.text;

      final auth = await api.login(nameSurname, pnr);

      if (auth != null) {
        final user = User.fromJson(auth["data"]["user"]);
        final reservation = Reservation.fromJson(auth["data"]["reservation"]);

        api.user = user;
        api.reservation = reservation;

        dynamic turnInfo;
        if (auth["data"]["reservation"]["appInfo"] != null) {
          turnInfo = TurnInfo.fromJson({
            ...auth["data"]["reservation"]["appInfo"],
            ...auth["data"]["reservation"]
          });
        } else {
          turnInfo = TurnInfo.fromJson({...auth["data"]["reservation"]});
        }

        api.turnInfo = turnInfo;

        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString("token", auth["token"]);

        prefs.setString("nameSurname", nameSurname);
        prefs.setString("pnr", pnr);

        final currentDate = DateTime.now();
        final expiration = DateTime(currentDate.year, 10, 1);
        String exp = "${expiration.year}-${expiration.month}-${expiration.day}";

        prefs.setString("auth-exiparion", exp);

        api.setNotifications(user.email, ref);

        context.loaderOverlay.hide();

        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DashboardPage()),
        );
      } else {
        ref.read(loginErrorProvider.notifier).state = true;
        context.loaderOverlay.hide();
        print('NO DATA');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      ref.read(loginErrorProvider.notifier).state = true;
      context.loaderOverlay.hide();
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future onInfoPnr() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
          return const InfoDialog(
            title: "Dove trovo il codice della  prenotazione?",
            description:
                "Il codice della prenotazione puoi trovarlo nella mail di conferma di prenotazione e nella mail che ti abbiamo inviato per il Pre-Partenza",
            imageUrl:
                "https://url",
          );
        });
  }

  checkRememberLogin() async {
    context.loaderOverlay.show();

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String? nameSurname = prefs.getString("nameSurname");
    String? pnr = prefs.getString("pnr");
    String? exp = prefs.getString("auth-exiparion");

    if (nameSurname != null && pnr != null && exp != null) {
      final today = DateTime.now();

      final expSplitted = exp.split("-");

      final expiration = DateTime(int.parse(expSplitted[0]),
          int.parse(expSplitted[1]), int.parse(expSplitted[2]));

      if (today.isBefore(expiration)) {
        _nameAndSurnameController.text = nameSurname;
        _pnrController.text = pnr;
        onLoginButtonPressed();
      }
    }
    context.loaderOverlay.hide();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    final bool loginError = ref.watch(loginErrorProvider);

    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
            child: Image.asset("assets/backgrounds/bg5.png",
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          CustomPaint(
            painter: _WaveCustomPaint(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
            size: Size.infinite,
          ),
          WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () async => false,
              child: Scaffold(
                resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
                appBar: AppBar(
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                body: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 22, bottom: 22, right: 22, top: 70),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset("assets/logo/logo.png", height: 70),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          SzInput(
                            ctrl: _nameAndSurnameController,
                            placeholder: "Inserisci nome",
                            label: "Inserisci nome e cognome",
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          SzInput(
                            ctrl: _pnrController,
                            placeholder: "Inserisci PNR",
                            label: "Codice prenotazione",
                            onInfoAction: onInfoPnr,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 24),
                          if (loginError == true)
                            Text(
                              "I dati inseriti risultano errati o inesistenti",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: HexColor("#FF0000"),
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          if (loginError == true) const SizedBox(height: 24),
                          LoginButton(
                            onAction: onLoginButtonPressed,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 100),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Component SzInput file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project/ui.dart';

class SzInput extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController ctrl;
  final String placeholder;
  final String label;
  final dynamic onInfoAction;

  const SzInput(
      {super.key,
      required this.ctrl,
      required this.placeholder,
      required this.label,
      this.onInfoAction});

  @override
  State<SzInput> createState() => _state();
}

class _state extends State<SzInput> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(widget.label,
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.black)),
            if (widget.onInfoAction != null) const SizedBox(width: 5),
            if (widget.onInfoAction != null)
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  widget.onInfoAction();
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.black, size: 17),
              ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 5,
        ),
        Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: widget.placeholder,
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: HexColor("#9492A1"),
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: HexColor("#9492A1"),
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            controller: widget.ctrl,
            // obscureText: true,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true` is not working nor `SingleChildScrollView` then what I did might not be your case I am adding some padding based on keyboard appearance but it will not to bottom you have scroll it your self following is the code

```
    CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom / 2),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // HEADING AND SUBHEADINGS
            const Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: HeadingLarge2(
                    text: "SIGN UP",
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 4),
                UnconstrainedBox(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 250,
                    child: LabelLargeRegular(
                      maxLines: 3,
                      align: TextAlign.center,
                      lineHeight: 1.35,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      text:
                          "Sign up now and start enjoying all the benefits our platform has to offer!",
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom this value does not update in real time but only if I perform hot restart with keyboard already open.
in short, the value does not change while opening the keyboard

Comment: It will not change on bottom modal other wise a direct interaction with scaffold it is working find I am using it at the moment and no issues at all working on both IOS and android.